# VPN: What should my Gateway remote ID be?

Tags: networking, vpn

I have a Netgear ProSafe UTM.

I set the Gateway local ID to it's WAN IP.  But I'm not sure what to put for it's Remote ID.

I want to be able to connect to it from a laptop across the internet.

I can chose between:

- Remote IP
- FQDN
- Client FQDN
- Cert DN

Frankly I've tried them messing around with them all but I'm just shooting in the dark, and the help desk docs are worthless.

Also, Googling around seems to end up with lots of pages not really related to what I want.  A lot of pages on configuring Cisco or Windows home networking or privacy advocates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually doesnt matter which you choose, as long as its the same at each end. (OK the cert DN is a bit more involved, but not much) Ive set up many netgear ipsec vpns, normally I set it up with FQDN. Just a quick run down of the options you have:
1. Remote IP - Exactly what it sounds like. goto whatismyip.com at your end and the remote end, your IP is your local ID, the remote IP is.... (guess what? :D )

FQDN - this is so that instead of an IP, you could assign a fully qualified domain name (like www.example.com) This option assumes that the public IP you get from whatismyip.com resolves to a name of some kind. If your broadband is with .... well almost anyone, it will undoubtedly have a name of some kind. Usually yourispusername.yourisp.com e.g. joeblogs.btconnect.com

I *think* Client FQDN is an email address, which could be the way to go given you are connecting via a laptop and i presume from a different IP everytime

So to flesh it out a bit, your local end might be something like:

```
Policy name="office2"
Exchange mode="Aggressive"
IdentifierType="Client FQDN"
Identifier="LynnOwens@lynnscompany.com"
EncryptionAlg=3DES
Authentication Algorithm = SHA-1
Authentication Method = Pre-shared key
Pre-shared key = mysharedsecret
Diffie-Hellman Group = Group 2 (1024 bit)
SA-Lifetime (sec) = 28800
Enable Dead Peer Detection = Yes
Detection Period = 10 seconds
Reconnect after failure count = 3
```

And at the remote end (the laptop)

```
Policy name="office2"
Exchange mode="Aggressive"
IdentifierType="Client FQDN"
Identifier="LynnOwens@lynnscompany.com"
EncryptionAlg=3DES
Authentication Algorithm = SHA-1
Authentication Method = Pre-shared key
Pre-shared key = mysharedsecret
Diffie-Hellman Group = Group 2 (1024 bit)
SA-Lifetime (sec) = 28800
Enable Dead Peer Detection = Yes
Detection Period = 10 seconds
Reconnect after failure count = 3
```

Now the only problem you have is what software you use to create the VPN connection. I found the inbuilt windows VPN client to be too unreliable. Netgear did have their own software (I say their own, it was actually badged) but a) this was a few years ago (~5) and b) they were charging for it at the time.
Which ever you decide, you will have to figure out where the above settings go, but it should be fairly obvious.

I also found this web page, you may not have seen, which deals with connecting to netgear vpn from Windows (Im presuming you are running windows on your laptop)

http://www.hackviking.com/2010/10/ipsec-vpn-with-netgear-fvs318v3/

Best of luck.
Dylan